# Import-Export Matrixfield data

Tags: matrix, migration, import

Have used the pretty neat [Import](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import) and [Export](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/export) plugins from Bob Olde Hamsink.

But, those two do not handle Matrix data.

The question is basically:

What is the 'most common way' to import and export data to/from Matrix fields in Craft CMS.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't handle exporting data, but [FeedMe](https://sgroup.com.au/plugins/feedme) can handle importing XML or JSON content for most element types.

Comment: Pricing

From the docs: 
https://sgroup.com.au/plugins/feedme/getting-started/pricing/
We love free stuff, and we're happy to announce Feed Me will always be available as a free version. You'll be able to import your content into Entries, but for all other Element Types such as Assets, Categories, Users and Commerce Products - you'll need the Pro version.

So it needs to be bought for the Matrix fields?

Comment: @HerraJon No - all fields are included in the free version - its the element types you want to import into (Assets, Categories, Users and Commerce Products) that the Pro version is for. Entries with Matrix fields are fine.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the sharp and shoot answer mate. I am gonna check this out but I really need something that can handle CSV files and such. Craft is as we know the "Content Friendly CMS" so there must be a way for this.

Comment: Most say that this plugin, FeedMe is amazing and simple to use. Highly reccomend it for Feeds-related import. Thanks and Good Work @crawf. I am still looking for a utility solution though. Would need to be able to import CSV content into matrix fields. There must be something of that sort?

Comment: A solution to add to this: @crawf pointed out to me a solution to my problem: Convert the CSV files to JSON and import that one through **FeedMe**. With the help of services like [http://www.csvjson.com/csv2json](http://www.csvjson.com/csv2json) this becomes a breeze. My problem is solved.